# pass the credentials of user to all views node.js

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, session, express

I'm trying to build an android application using node.js web services,the first interface allow the user to connect to a host using ip address,login and password, so he can get all the databases,i want to save the object credentials to use in all other routes,i tried express-session but it didnt worked.
Any solution?

```
app.post('/connect',function(req,res){
    sess=req.session;
    sess.user=req.body.user;
    sess.password=req.body.password;
    sess.server=req.body.server;
    sess.database=req.body.database;
    console.log(sess)
    user = req.body.user;
    password = req.body.password;
    server = req.body.server;
    database = req.body.database;

    var config = {
        user: user,
        password: password,
        server: server,
        database: database
    };



    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        if (err)  {res.json({success: false, message: "error connexion to SQL Server"});
            sql.close()}
        else{

            res.json({success: true, message: "connexion established to SQL Server"});

            sql.close();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Look up Passport.js. It uses either Express sessions or Json Web Tokens.

Comment: It's not the solution that i'm looking for

Comment: Why is that not your solution? What exactly is your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the request make by http lib of android (or another) which is not a browse then `express-session` will not work. Your server must be like a API server, client(android) request login server response a token (api key or the same), in next request client push data embeded token and server side can credentials the request. I suggest read about JWT (Json Web Token) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy if you are using express module in node application.
You basically create routes using express and can pass the required data to the appropriate routes and views as follows

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('category', 
    { 
      videodata: vd
    });
});
```

Here while rendering the response, the data that is to be passed is also included. It's name is `videodata` and value is `vd`